# I would like to know how to test if the compiledStatement in sqlite return an answer or not, without missing the first line

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I would like to test if the SQL return a result. If there is no result, I would like to send a message. The problem is that when I do that test, the first row is skipped when I want to do my process (when rows are found).

```
NSString *selectSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT z_pk, zpostcode, zname, zfirstname, zstreetname, zstreetnumber, zcity FROM ZTAB_PARTICULIER where UPPER(ZNAME) like \'\%%%@%%\' and ZPOSTCODE like \'\%%%@%%\'", [self.name.text  uppercaseString], self.postcode.text];

const char *query_stmt = [selectSQL UTF8String];

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;


//Compilation de la requete et verification du succes
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Prepare Database OK");

    int stat = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
    if (stat == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO ROWS!");
    }
    while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
    ...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but do not use `stringWithFormat` to insert text values into  SQL statement. E.g. try your code searching for "Joe's Bar", and `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will fail. Instead, use `?` placeholder in your SQL 
(without quotes around it), and use [`sqlite3_bind_text`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). Or use a library like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) which simplifies the binding process.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am going to use it. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove that first call to `sqlite3_step`. Just have a counter that you increment in your `while` loop, and after the `while` loop, just see if that counter was zero or not.

For example, you might do:

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query_stmt, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Prepare Database OK");

    // int stat = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
    // if (stat == SQLITE_DONE)
    // {
    //     NSLog(@"NO ROWS!");
    // }

    NSInteger rows = 0;
    int rc;

    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(compiledStatement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        rows++;

        ...
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSLog(@"Some error %s (%ld)", sqlite3_errmsg(), (long)rc);
    }

    if (rows == 0) {
        NSLog(@"NO ROWS!");
    }

    ...
```

Something like that checks for not only "no rows" situation, but also checks for errors.

Comment: Oh ok, I am goin' to use that. I believed that there was a way with the "SQLITE_DONE ". Thank you.